# Web page saving

Tags: html, web, webpage, save-as

I want to save a web page as a HTML document, that I can have access to this web page with all subsites forever, because the web page will close by the end of this year. So the web page won’t exist anymore.

This web page has a course and it’s hosted by „Memberspot“, which is an e-learning platform. In this web page I’ve got an account with login datas of email and password.

I want furthermore to access all files and videos of this web page.

**What I’ve tried:**

I’ve saved the web page as a HTML document through Safari and Google Chrome. If I open this saved HTML document, then it opens a browser with the link of the web page. First I need to login to see the contents of the web page.

I don’t think, that I have access to this web page forever in this way.

**Questions:**

How can I save a web page just for myself and only for my purposes forever, even with an account?

How can I save the web page, so it doesn’t need to open the browser and without login, so I have access to this web page forever?

Comment: Have you tried to save the page as `.mhtml` or as `.html` ? You should use  `.mhtml`. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I just downloaded the web page through Safari and Google Chrome with the button "save as" and the sharing button as a html document, so .html. I don't know about something like .mhtml.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the page as `.mhtml` (rather than `.html`).

The [MHTML format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) :

> Web archive file format used to combine, in a single computer file, the HTML code and its companion resources (such as images) that are represented by external hyperlinks in the web page's HTML code. The content of an MHTML file is encoded using the same techniques that were first developed for HTML email messages, using the MIME content type multipart/related.[1] MHTML files use an .mhtml or .mht filename extension.

This format is recognized by most browsers and includes the webpage
and all the resources that it includes. It's a method for archiving
webpages, which is what you're looking for.